# Single Quotes not fully supported in AD B2C email addresses

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I've noticed that I can't log in via AD B2C with email addresses with single quotes in. It's working when there's an ’ (char code 8217) in the email address, but not ' (char code 39 (standard single quote)).

This is blocked in the UI, and if I manually change the RegEx pattern on the login page it allows me to log in, and it seems to be functioning correctly. Weirdly enough you can create accounts with ' in the email address, just not sign in. Has anyone experienced this? Has anyone found a way to modify the RegEx?

The input tag that gets injected by AD B2C in our custom login page is as follows:

```html
<input type='email' id='logonIdentifier'
  name='Username or email address'
  pattern='^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$'
  placeholder='Email Address'
  value='' tabindex='1'>
```

There you can see that only the awkward quote, ’, is accepted, and not the sexier and preferred '.

Comment: Hi @Molibar: Are you using built-in or custom policies?

Comment: Built-in; signup/signin.

Answer (score 1):

Response from Microsoft:

"It is getting fixed, they started working on it but it requires a core policy update which might take some time to have it reflected on the production.
I don’t have an ETA yet."

---

I haven't found any way to get around this, but at least it's getting worked on.

Comment: Any update on this?  I seem to be experiencing a similar issue.  I'm doing a look up to against the B2C graph api for users by email, and I have an email containing a ' and this is returning a bad request error code.

Answer (score 0):

The Sign in (Recommended) flow appears to support this from Page Layout Version 2.1.2